# Swift - Save all documents of firestore collection in a list of objects

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to retrieve all the documents of a firestore collection, and then write it in an object then append it my list of objects.
after that i display it in an UITableView.

Here is what I have, it works without errors but when I run it, nothing is displayed.

**The list structure:**

```
struct RewardsStruct {
//var rewardKey: String
var Reward: String
var noPoints: String
var QRimageURL: ImageURL = ImageURL(url: nil, didLoad: false)
var Desc: String
var isvalid: Bool
```

}

**Here is my retrieving code:**

```
private func getRewards() {
    var rewardsList = [RewardsStruct]()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("Rewards").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                 let code = RewardsStruct( Reward: document.data()["Reward"] as! String , noPoints: document.data()["noPoints"] as! String , QRimageURL: document.data()["QRimageURL"] as! ImageURL, Desc:document.data()["Desc"] as! String, isvalid: (document.data()["isvalid"] != nil) )
                
                    self.rewardsList.append(code)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.CodeTable.reloadData()
                    }
                
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

**The rest of code in ViewController as some requests**

```
class RewardsVC: UIViewController {

var rewardsList = [RewardsStruct]()

var reward:RewardsStruct!

@IBOutlet weak var infoView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var ViewLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var CodeTable: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    CodeTable.delegate = self
    CodeTable.dataSource = self
    ViewLabel.isHidden = true

    infoView.makeCornerRounded(cornerRadius: 30, maskedCorners: [.layerMinXMinYCorner, .layerMaxXMinYCorner])
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    rewardsList.removeAll()
    getRewards()
    

}


private func getRewards() {
    ....
```

}

```
extension RewardsVC: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    CodeTable.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "#F5F5F5")
    return 60
    
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 125
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    print("List number of rows")
    print(rewardsList.count)
    return rewardsList.count
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RewardsCell") as! RewardsCell
    let object = rewardsList[indexPath.row]
    
    cell.Reward.text = object.Reward
    cell.Desc.text = object.Desc
    cell.noPoints.text = "-" + object.noPoints + " Points"
    
    return cell
}

   
    
func addShadow(backgroundColor: UIColor = .white, cornerRadius: CGFloat = 12, shadowRadius: CGFloat = 5, shadowOpacity: Float = 0.1, shadowPathInset: (dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat), shadowPathOffset: (dx: CGFloat, dy: CGFloat)) {
    
} }
```

**Here is my FireStore:**

[image: FireStore structure]

Comment: there are many ways to save your firestore collection to a list. Look-up asynchronous function with completion handler. The crux is to pass your `var rewardsList = [RewardsStruct]()` to outside of your `getRewards()` function.

Comment: Could we get a look at the whole class (view controller), would really help to get a better idea on how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example code, to `...save all documents of firestore collection in a list of objects...`.

`getRewards(...)` is called an asynchronous function, and needs a way to "wait" for the results to be available before you can use them.

There are many ways to do this, here I present an example code that uses a completion handler to pass the results (or errors) of `getRewards(...)` back to the calling function. Note, the code is untested since I do not have your database (or even Firestore).

```
// -- here some error type for testing
enum FireError: Error {
    case decodingError
    case badError
    // ...
}

// -- here completion handler
private func getRewards(completion: @escaping ([RewardsStruct], FireError?) -> ()) {

    var rewardsList = [RewardsStruct]()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("Rewards").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            completion([], FireError.badError)  // <-- here
        } else {
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                 let code = RewardsStruct(Reward: document.data()["Reward"] as! String , noPoints: document.data()["noPoints"] as! String , QRimageURL: document.data()["QRimageURL"] as! ImageURL, Desc:document.data()["Desc"] as! String, isvalid: (document.data()["isvalid"] != nil) )                    
                 self.rewardsList.append(code)
            }
            completion(rewardsList, nil)  // <-- here
        }
    }
}
```

Use the function like this:

```
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    
    getRewards() { results, error in  // <-- here
        if error == nil {
            rewardsList.removeAll()
            rewardsList = results
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.CodeTable.reloadData()
            }
        } else {
            // todo deal with errors
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use this code, without using a completion handler, since `getRewards(...)` is inside your UIViewController.

```
private func getRewards() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    db.collection("Rewards").getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        } else {
            self.rewardsList.removeAll()  // <-- here
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
                 let code = RewardsStruct(Reward: document.data()["Reward"] as! String , noPoints: document.data()["noPoints"] as! String , QRimageURL: document.data()["QRimageURL"] as! ImageURL, Desc:document.data()["Desc"] as! String, isvalid: (document.data()["isvalid"] != nil) )
                 self.rewardsList.append(code)  // <-- here
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {    // <-- here
                self.CodeTable.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    getRewards()
}
```

Comment: did my answer not work for you?